# MySQL connection execution in Ruby error handling

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do I do error handling with something like this in RoR:

```
conn = Person.connection
conn.execute(sql_stmt)
```

What if there were errors while executing the SQL?

Answer (score 1):

The [`execute` method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/AbstractMysqlAdapter.html#method-i-execute) is just a wrapper for the connection's `query` method and that will raise an `Mysql::Error` exception if something is wrong. If you use mysql2 instead of the older mysql gem, then I think you'll get a `Mysql2::Error` exception.